# How to pass java.util.date in REST urls using Jersey REST cleint

Tags: java, spring, jersey-client

In my `Java` `Spring MVC` web application, I use `Jersey` REST client. I am trying to get some data by sending two `Date` objects to the server. But I am unable to use the Date objects in the urls. I am afraid if I convert them to string, I might not be able to get the exact timestamp in my server side. My url would be:

```
RESTDomain/siteid/{siteid}/pickupdate/{pickupdate}/returndate/{returndate}/pickuplocation/{pickuplocation}/returnlocation/{returnlocation}
```

So with data in them, it would look like:

```
/siteid/5/pickupdate/Thu Apr 14 00:00:00 IST 2016/returndate/Fri Apr 29 00:01:00 IST 2016/pickuplocation/1/returnlocation/1
```

And my controller would be :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(
  value = "/siteid/{siteid}/pickupdate/{pickupdate}/returndate/{returndate}/pickuplocation/{pickuplocation}/returnlocation/{returnlocation}",
  method = RequestMethod.GET,
  headers = "Accept=application/json"
)
public CarDetailsListHB getDetails(
  @ModelAttribute("siteid") int siteId,
  @ModelAttribute("pickuplocation") int pickUpLocation,
  @ModelAttribute("returndate") Date returnDate,
  @ModelAttribute("pickupdate") Date pickupDate, 
  @ModelAttribute("returnlocation") int returnLocation,
  ModelMap model
) {
  //logic here
}
```

Is there any solution for this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as a String and convert to the required format.Below code takes the String and returns the java.util.Date in the same format as the passed String.
Check the below:

```
//your date as String
String date="Thu Apr 14 00:00:00 IST 2016";
            SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
            Date returnDate=dateformat.parse(date);//returnDate will have the Date object in same format.
            System.out.println(returnDate);
```

Your `@ModelAttribute("returndate") String returnDate` should be of String type.
and in your controller method

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
                Date newReturnDate=dateformat.parse(returnDate);//newReturnDate will have the Date object in same format.
```

For modifying the time part you can try the below:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(newReturnDate);

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,11 );
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,39 );   
            newReturnDate=cal.getTime();
            System.out.println(newReturnDate);
```

So newReturnDate will have the updated time.You would need to get the int values(hour and minute part) from your String "11:39".

Comment: I have Date  date="Thu Apr 14 00:00:00 IST 2016", its not string initially.

Comment: so if I use the toString() function here, will that be fine

Comment: from where are you passing data to the controller?Anyways toString() also gives the equivalent String data,check that and see.

Comment: I get the date from as result of a form submission. Also If I have a Date object like Thu Apr 14 00:00:00 IST 2016 and a String with time as 11:39 AM, can I somehow join them to for the date string like Fri Apr 01 11:39:31 IST 2016